# Trying to Paint Several Objects in Java

Tags: java, timer, actionlistener, paintcomponent, repaint

So I have a class called Game that contains an ArrayList of objects that I'd like to paint, and a timer. They all implement ActionListener.
I have actionPerformed in Game loop through the ArrayList and call actionPerformed for each item. Then, each object's actionPerformed method calls repaint. However, this only seems to paint the last object in the ArrayList.

I put some test prints in each object's actionPerformed method, and the program does get to the repaint line for all the objects.

It looks something like:

```
public class Game extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    public ArrayList<GameObject> things = new ArrayList<GameObject>();
    public Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
    public Game ()
    {
        super();
        this.setSize(620, 440);
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        this.setLocation(dim.width/2-this.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-this.getSize().height/2);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);

        this.setTitle("Moving Ball");
        GameObject b = new Ball(this);
        GameObject p = new Paddle(this);
        things.add(b);
        things.add(p);


        for (int i = 0; i < things.size(); i++)
        {
            this.add(things.get(i));
        }

        t.start();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < things.size(); i++)
        {
            things.get(i).actionPerformed(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And the game objects have overwritten paintComponent and contain:

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
{
    //...
    repaint();
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't trigger the action listener anywhere. You should add a line of

```
things.get(i).addActionListener(this);
```

in a proper place. Looks like this:

```
public class Game extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    public ArrayList<GameObject> things = new ArrayList<GameObject>();
    public Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
    public Game ()
    {
        super();
        this.setSize(620, 440);
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        this.setLocation(dim.width/2-this.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-this.getSize().height/2);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);

        this.setTitle("Moving Ball");
        GameObject b = new Ball(this);
        GameObject p = new Paddle(this);
        things.add(b);
        things.add(p);


        for (int i = 0; i < things.size(); i++)
        {
            this.add(things.get(i));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < things.size(); i++)
        {
            things.get(i).addActionListener(this);
        }

        t.start();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
        //repaint your gameobject
    }
}
```

Comment: So since my GameObject extends JPanel, I can't use addActionObject on them, but I can use it on the Timer. So I tried both the loop with t.addActionObject(things.get(i)); and t.addActionObject(this);. Naturally, those didn't work.

Comment: When I intialized my Timer with this, that was effectively doing t.addActionObject(this), and since every time the Timer event occurs, Game executes actionPerformed which executes each GameObject's actionPerformed, and that is effectively the same as doing t.addActionObject(things.get(i)).

Comment: It seems to me that my actual problem is that I have multiple JPanels being added to my JFrame. I tried just adding a main panel to my JFrame and adding my GameObject panels to the main panel, but that did not work.